# Imported OBJ is super dark

Tags: lighting, shadows, obj

I did a 3D scan, imported the obj and removed the material. For some reason, it shows up super dark in the viewport and in cycles render view. I've played with the materials but it keeps showing up dark with weird shadows. I don't need the original image texture (which also shows up dark), I just need to add my own material shader.

[image]

Here is another scan from the same day, where it shows up fine (on the same .blend file, light, settings, etc.)
[image]

I'm not sure if the OBJ got corrupted or something but this is the only scan I have of this pose. It doesn't seem to be a problem with the lighting/HDRI but rather the OBJ itself. Anyone know how to fix this weird lighting? Tysm

Comment: Have you tried to add other objects to the scene with materials to compare?  Have you opened up any associated image file to look at what is incorporated in the object's material?  I suggest that you edit your question to add this information.  You can add a brightness/contrast node to the output of the Image Texture node that could help you solve this problem, or use a Photoshop-like image editor to adjust/compensate.

Comment: Have you also checked normals of the mesh, or would you mind giving a screenshot of the material setup in the shader editor?

Comment: Maybe try a Clear Custom Split Normals Data in Object Data panel > Geometry Data?

Comment: I had a similar problem and i fixed it with turning off auto smothing.

Comment: show me the .blend and I'll tell you